# How can I fix my table to make a expiration of medicine?

Tags: mysql

I'm doing an inventory system of drug store. And now I'm trying to do the expiration of medicine. I want to show you my table. Maybe you have an idea of how to fix my tables. I put the expiration date in tbl_received_order. When I received a medicine it will insert into tbl_medicine. What if the customer bought 50 pieces of paracetamol or supplier_med_id is equal to 3. And after two months the medicine received will be expired. I use `DATE(NOW()) > tbl_received_order.expiration_date` to get all the expired medicine. 
My problem is that the `qty` is not tally to `rec_qty` when the medicine expired. Just for below example, I have 100 pcs. on my initial inventory. But later on, 50 pcs. was sold. Why is it 100 pcs.is still reflecting on my inventory of medicines for expiration, instead of 50pcs. How can I fix my table? Can somebody help me with my problem?

The is my table

```
tbl_medicine

med_id  supplier_med_id  qty    status   branch_id
1       3                50     Active   1
2       7                100    Active   1
3       9                100    Active   1
```

```
tbl_received_order

received_id  user_id  purchase_order_id   date_received 
RO20190001   1        PO20190001          2019-05-04
```

```
tbl_received_order_details

id    received_id    supplier_med_id   rec_qty   expiration_date
1     RO20190001     3                 100       2019-11-04
2     RO20190001     7                 100       2019-11-04
3     RO20190001     9                 100       2019-11-04
1     RO20190002     3                 50        2019-11-04
2     RO20190002     7                 50        2019-11-04
3     RO20190002     9                 50        2019-11-04
```

```
tbl_transaction

transaction_id  customer_id  user_id  transaction_date  branch_id
0001            CU2018001    1        2019-09-04        1
0002            CU2018001    1        2019-09-04        1
0003            CU2018001    1        2019-09-04        1
```

```
tbl_transaction_details

details_id   transaction_id  supplier_med_id   qty    price    total_price
1            0001            3                 50     10.00    500
2            0002            3                 10     10.00    100
3            0003            3                 10     10.00    100
```

Comment: Do you store the quantity bought by a customer both in `tbl_medicine` and `tbl_transaction_details`?

Comment: @Samir no only in `tbl_transaction_details`...

Comment: check my answer. It should get what you need.

Comment: @Samir But what if aside from `supplier_med_id 3, 10 pcs of `supplier_med_id 7` was also sold? How can I reflect these two transactions in one display? You use static in WHERE clause

Comment: you can do it using `GROUP BY`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @Samir what if the tbl_received_order_details has two or more same supplier_med_id? It can be both of them are expired or maybe not. I use the `GROUP BY `supplier_med_id` but it adds it two times

Comment: can you please throw some light on 'adds it two times'?

Comment: @Samir Here's my query
   `SELECT  ABS(SUM(COALESCE(ordered.quantity,0)) - 
    SUM(COALESCE(transact.quantity, 0))) AS Quantity, ordered.expiration_date 
    FROM tbl_received_order_details AS ordered
    LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction_details AS transact ON 
    ordered.supplier_medicine_id = transact.supplier_medicine_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_medicine ON tbl_medicine.supplier_medicine_id = 
    ordered.supplier_medicine_id
                WHERE ordered.expiration_date <= DATE(NOW()) AND barangay_id = 
    1
                GROUP BY ordered.supplier_medicine_id HAVING Quantity > 0`

Comment: Query looks fine to me. It will help debug if you can create a sql fiddle and share it with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199200/discussion-between-bayanihan-4-and-samir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the accurate quantity by using a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT orderd.expiration_date, orderd.rec_qty - SUM(trans.qty) AS inventory_left
FROM tbl_received_order_details AS orderd
JOIN tbl_transaction_details AS trans
ON orderd.supplier_med_id = trans.supplier_med_id
WHERE orderd.supplier_med_id = 3
AND orderd.expiration_date < '2019-11-05'
```

Join `tbl_received_order_details` and `tbl_transaction_details` using `supplier_med_id`.

Filter the records with medicine id '3' and an expiration date.

Since there can be more than 1 transaction for a particular medicine, we need to `SUM` the quantity sold and subtract it from total quantity to get what's left.

**Update 1**

Above query will get expired medicines for the ones sold. To get quantity left for all inventories sold, use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT orderd.expiration_date, orderd.rec_qty - SUM(trans.qty) AS inventory_left
FROM tbl_received_order_details AS orderd
JOIN tbl_transaction_details AS trans
ON orderd.supplier_med_id = trans.supplier_med_id
WHERE orderd.expiration_date < '2019-11-05'
GROUP BY orderd.supplier_med_id
```

**UPDATE 2**

To get all left inventories that are expired whether they are sold or not, use `LEFT JOIN`. `COALESCE(trans.qty, 0)` will return first `NOT NULL` value. So if a medicine is never sold, it will not have any entry in transaction table which will return qty as NULL. In such cases, we will subtract zero from `rec_qty` which in turn will get complete rec_qty as left overs.

```
SELECT orderd.expiration_date, orderd.rec_qty - SUM(COALESCE(trans.qty, 0)) AS inventory_left
FROM tbl_received_order_details AS orderd
LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction_details AS trans
ON orderd.supplier_med_id = trans.supplier_med_id
WHERE orderd.expiration_date < '2019-11-05'
GROUP BY orderd.supplier_med_id
```

Comment: This what I wanted! Glad you're here

Comment: You're welcome! You can upvote it too :)
Have added one more query which will help you get all remaining quantities whether they are sold or not. So if `supplier_med_id` 9 is never sold, still you would want their numbers when expired.